# looping through list in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a dictionary:

```
babies = {'clothes list':['a','b','c','d'], 'lots of toys': 'yes'}
```

Now in the template I want to do the equivalent of:

```
for cloth in babies['clothes list']:
    print cloth
```

I have filter key_lookup defined. So doing this works in template:

```
{{ babies|key_lookup:'lots of toys' }}
```

But doing

```
{% for cloth in babies|key_lookup:'clothes list' %}
```

doesn't work.

The above dictionary is just an example. I can not modify the dictionary keys.
key_lookup is defined as

```
def key_lookup(the_dict, key):
   return the_dict.get(key, None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#with)? If it's just a syntax issue, this might work:

```
{% with clothes=babies|key_lookup:'clothes list' %}
    {% for cloth in clothes %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: nrabinowitz that works..thanks. django-templates why do you make it so hard?

Comment: @Ben - I think the syntax above was added in Django 1.3 - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#with). The older syntax is still supported, but I think you have it backwards: `with babies|... as clothes`

Comment: @nrabinowitz - you're right! Thanks, I didn't realise the syntax had changed. And, yes, I got it backwards - oops :)